# Что быстрее: данные из подзапроса или из LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос, производительность

Реализую двухступенчатый поиск в большой БД на MySQL: сначала беглый по хэшу, затем детальный по всем полям. Какой из следующих вариантов SQL-запроса будет работать быстрее? Индекс в таблице составной из ID и хэша (хотя ID у всех уникальный, хэш только для скорости обработки).

1) Передавать данные напрямую из вложенного запроса:

```
SELECT <детальная проверка по 150 полям> AS matched_2
FROM (
    SELECT ID, <150 полей>, <первичная проверка по хэшу> AS matched_1
    FROM table
    HAVING matched_1 > 0.5
) AS basic
HAVING matched_2 > 0.7
ORDER BY matched_2
```

2) Или же на внешний приделать LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT <детальная проверка по 150 полям> AS matched_2
FROM (
    SELECT ID, <первичная проверка по хэшу> AS matched_1
    FROM table
    HAVING matched_1 > 0.5
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID, <150 полей> FROM table
) AS t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
HAVING matched_2 > 0.7
ORDER BY matched_2
```

Любые другие советы по оптимизации очень приветствуются.

Comment: а план выполнения что показывает для первого и второго случаев?

Comment: @Grundy Вы про `EXPLAIN`? Пока что у меня ещё нет хэш-колонки, не могу сформировать запрос.

Comment: ага, я про него

Comment: @Grundy накидал фэйковые запросы, где использовал лишь 3 поля, а роль хэша сыграл один из ключей, query_cost получились такие: 14409 и 28654. Но он прогнозирует JOIN всех строк друг с другом, как бы без фильтрации, а по-факту второй вариант может оказаться куда производительнее.

Comment: А зачем вы делаете left join с подзапросом, когда можно сделать простой join с исходной таблицей?

Comment: @PavelMayorov чтобы сделать join по уже отфильтрованной изначальной таблице. Если объединить, то (на мой, не самой точный взгляд) будет объединяться по всем строкам из таблицы, ведь where не работает на вычисляемые поля, а having используется уже после join’ов.

Comment: @AivanF. вы ошибаетесь

Comment: @PavelMayorov кажется мы друг друга недопоняли, вы про подзапрос с `t2`, что вместо него можно использовать саму таблицу? Это конечно да! Только на производительность никак не повлияет, и `EXPLAIN` даёт точно такой же вывод :) А в виде написал подзапроса для упрощения восприятия, чтобы читающему было понятно беглым взглядом, откуда конкретно появляются 150 полей. Да и в целом, вопрос же про эффективность самого JOIN'a, и стоит ли его здесь использовать..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правда (выявленная экспериментальным путём) оказалась чуточку сложнее и интереснее: у каждого варианта есть свой оптимальный вариант применения.

- Если после первого этапа поиска остаётся ещё много^ строк, то быстрее работает прямая передача данных (в моём примере `39.8` vs `46.5` secs).
- Если после фильтрации остаётся немного^ строк, то использование LEFT JOIN'a оправдывает себя (`14.5` vs `16.5` secs).

^ – конечно, понятия *много/немного* очень индивидуальны, для каждого проекта надо смотреть конкретные числа.

---

Предполагаю, что время исполнения этих двух вариантов кода можно математически описать так:

```
T1 = N * s1 + N * r + F * s2
T2 = N * s1 + F * r + F * s2 + F * j
```

Где:

- `N` – количество строк в таблице
- `F` – количество строк после первой фильтрации
- `s1`, `s2` – время фильтрации одной строки в первом и втором этапе
- `r` – время считывания тех 150 полей для одной строки
- `j` – время на обработку JOIN'a одной строки

Тогда выбор оптимального варианта будет определяться знаком неравенства между `N * b` и `F * b + F * j` –  а единственный изменяющийся параметр здесь это `F`, от него-то всё и зависит: чем он меньше, тем более выгоден второй вариант, и наоборот.